# capturing key strokes in PyCharm debug console

Tags: debugging, pycharm

PyCharm has a nice debug console where you can see the program's output. I have an interactive program that captures user key strokes. It works well in command shells, however it doesn't capture key strokes in PyCharm's debug console. "Show command line" doesn't help as well, as PyCharm captures anything written there.

Is there a way to set the console so that the key strokes will reach the running program?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to read keystrokes without waiting for enter/return. I ended up using this code that would give me a getch() which doesn't wait for enter/return normally but still works in the PyCharm debugger (using enter/return) enough to debug:

```
def getchfunc():
    import termios
    import sys, tty
    if sys.stdin.isatty():
        def _getch():
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                tty.setraw(fd)
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
            finally:
                termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            return ch

    else:
        def _getch():
            return sys.stdin.read(1)
    return _getch
```